# Javascript global variable issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, window, global

I'm really confused with global variables in javascript. I made a global variable that sits outside of every code. I added stuff to it in one function then I called it in another function to check the length, but the length is zero! I did thorough testing to see if elements were being added and they were. Here are snippets of my code:

```
window.friendArr = [];
AjaxIM = function(options, actions) {
if(this instanceof AjaxIM) {
    var self = this;

    // === {{{ defaults }}} ===
    //
    // These are the available settings for Ajax IM, and the associated
    // defaults:
```

This is the global declaration^

Any input or even a hint in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to update a global variable in an AJAX call? Seems like this common question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: More code or explanation is needed.

Comment: "*I added stuff to it in one function then I called it in another function to check the length*" Can we see those functions?